# How to do conditional includes of partials in hoganjs with expressjs? (using hogan-express module)

Tags: node.js, express, angularjs, hogan.js

I'm using express 3.0.x  with hogan-express as template engine to build a single page application.

I would like to add a partial that will contain information that will help me to develop / debug the application. (I am also working with angularjs)

Depending on a variable somewhere in my app, like "devMode = true" I'd like to include this particular partial and it won't be included if "devMode = false".

Here are my files

index.js (routes):

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.locals = {
        template_engine: 'HoganJS'
    }

    return res.render(
        'index',
        {
            partials:
            {
                head: 'head', foot: 'foot'
            }
        }
        );
};

exports.partials = function(req, res) {

    res.render('partials/' + req.params.entity + '/' + req.params.name)
}
```

index.html:

```
[[> head]]

<div class="navbar fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="/">My app</a>
        <ul class="nav">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>



[[> foot]]
```

(I changed {{ }} to [[ ]] to resolve conflict with angularjs syntax)

I'd like to include something like [[>dev]] before [[> foot]] depending on a boolean somewhere in my app.

Thank you for any help:)

Comment: you will have to add that variable to the context (data) you render with {dev: true}